# How do Linux terminal programs set up the environment for the shell program

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell, zsh

I am writing a terminal emulator in Rust. The source is [here](https://github.com/adamsoutar/velocity/blob/linux/velocity-core/src/shell_layer/linux.rs#L103). It forks itself and the child process (eventually) becomes the shell program which it reads output from and passes input to.

On macOS, what I do is execute `login -f adam` (my username is adam), and that works and spawns the shell program with env set up.

On Linux, I can't do that. `login` on Linux needs `sudo`. When you start a normal Linux terminal program it doesn't ask for your password in order to do `sudo`, so it must be something else. I saw that Zsh has a `-l` flag that makes it a "login shell". **But** this does not set up important environment variables like `$PATH`.

See this screenshot:

[image]

The left is `sudo login -f adam` - it's almost right, but it makes me put in my password.

The right is `/usr/bin/zsh -l`. It doesn't ask for my password, but it *doesn't* set `$PATH` or reset `$PWD` to `/home/adam`, among many other things.

So my question is, how does a normal Linux terminal program like `xterm` start up, and set up all of your environment etc. without executing the `login` binary?

Comment: *I'm not a programmer*, but: (1) Doesn't your terminal emulator inherit a sane `$PATH` from your desktop environment? I don't know Rust, but there should be a way to spawn a child that inherits the environment along with `$PATH`. (2) In general the parent is responsible for choosing a working directory for a child. // In terms of system calls, after `fork(2)` you need to `chdir(2)` and then to pass the right `envp` when you `execve(2)`. I think if you do this then you can straightforwardly run a shell (with or without `-l`). Optionally [do this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/605270/108618).

Comment: I'm not familiar with macOS, but invoking `login` doesn't sound to be the right thing to me. A graphical terminal emulator is not where you log in, nor where you authenticate against the system. It's "just" a regular app, in turn launching yet another app (typically the shell), with the regular permission and inheritence things going on. The terminal emulator is responsible for setting up the env vars related to terminal emulation (like `TERM`), not the rest. I'm really wondering, how come `PATH` is not properly set up prior to launching the terminal, or then presumably any other app??

Comment: ... Most env vars should already be set up prior to launching the terminal emulator, or set up later inside by the shell, via its startup files. Many people prefer to launch a "login shell" in the terminal, but I personally find this the wrong approach again for the same reason: it's not where you log in. ... Unrelated to this: Starting up in the invoking context's working directory (as many terminal emulators do), rather than in your home dir, is not wrong per se. Sure it might not be your preferred behavior, then do a `chdir()`, but it's not "wrong" as you claim in the screenshot.